# C++ error: not a member OR multiple definition

Tags: c++, static, constants

I am trying to use a static const field which I define inside a class.
When I define it like that:

```
class DisjunctionQuery : public Query
{

  public:
    DisjunctionQuery ();
    static const std::string prefix;


};
const std::string DisjunctionQuery::prefix = "Or";
```

It says: multiple definition of 'DisjunctionQuery::prefix'
and if I change it that way (remove the two lines):

```
class DisjunctionQuery : public Query
{

  public:
    DisjunctionQuery ();
    //static const std::string prefix;


};
//const std::string DisjunctionQuery::prefix = "Or";
```

It says when I try to call it in another place 'prefix' is not a member of 'DisjunctionQuery'.

How can I make it work?
thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You move the definition to a single implementation file.

If you keep it in the header, you'll break the **one definition rule**. Each file that includes the header will attempt to define the `static` member, which is wrong.

```
//DisjunctionQuery.h
class DisjunctionQuery : public Query
{
  public:
    //....
    static const std::string prefix;
};

//DisjunctionQuery.cpp
#include "DisjunctionQuery.h"
const std::string DisjunctionQuery::prefix = "Or";
```

Comment: s/will attempt to define/will attempt to implement/.  The definition is within the class definition; the multiple-implementation scenario is the problem.

Comment: @cdhowie no, that's just a declaration. Also, there's no implementation for data members, only for functions.

Comment: You assume tomer doesn't add include guards.

Comment: @user1417475 include guards don't matter. I'm talking about inclusion in multiple translation units, so include guards are irrelevant.